# Is it appropriate to ask same question about same programming language, but different version?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

To be specific, I am trying to ask a question about some feature of c++, but found a answer which states that the feature was not available in c++11. However, technology evolves, and the feature might be available in later standards like c++17,(or 20). Is it appropriate to ask in the Stackoverflow whether the feature is available in recent standard?

Comment: Did the post you find ask specifically about C++11, or about C++ in general?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201506/is-constexpr-based-computation-turing-complete Not so sure.. In the context, it seems to deal with "new feature in C++", constexpr, but it also has general C++ tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends. Just asking something like

> Feature X has not been supported in C++11, is it available in some newer standard?

will probably not be received well because it lacks some research on your side. Do you have any indication that this feature is available? Did you check the feature lists of the newer standards? If you have and there is nothing listed, then asking doesn't make much sense. If there is a feature similar to what you need, you might be able to ask something like

> I want to do Y. In C++11 this was not directly possible since feature X has not been supported. But in C++17 there is the new feature Z, is it now possible to do Y more easily?

**TL;DR**: Do your own research first, only then ask.

Comment: quoting the old question and explaining it doesn't answer your question is also a good idea to avoid FFGITW dupe closes